# How can I use `-rewrite-objc` to transform the block in `.c` to the right `.cpp` file in ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

In the book, *Pro multithreading and memory management for iOS and OS X*, section 2.3, the author said the following code can be transformed to a `.cpp` code:

```
typedef int (^blk_t)(int);
blk_t func(int rate) {
    return ^(int count){return rate * count;};
}
```

`.cpp` code:

```
blk func(int rate) {
    blk_t tmp = &__func_block_impl_0 (
        __func_block_func_0, &__func_block_desc_0_DATA, rate
    );
    tmp = objc_retainBlock(tmp);
    return objc_autoreleaseReturnValue(tmp);
}
```

But I can't get it by using `clang -rewrite-objc -fobjc-arc block.c`, and this is my result, following:

[image]

So, how can I get the right result as the book description? And what's the right clang command which can transform c/cpp/objc to cpp in ARC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate Objective-C code to C++ with ARC enabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950466/how-to-translate-objective-c-code-to-c-with-arc-enabling)

Answer (score 0):

use `clang -rewrite-objc fileName.c/m` to try.

Comment: My zsh show clang: error: no such file or directory: 'test.cpp/m' .  And do you mean '-m' parameter? And the '-m' is also defined in the help ) : .. I have no idea .

Comment: `fileName.c/m` it means the fileName end with `.c` or `.m`。
so,you can use `clang -rewrite-objc fileName.c` in your Demo.